# How do I update a single integer in a json document using jq?

Tags: json, jq

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) I want to update an `integer` in a JSON file from an environment variable but the attribute is being parsed as a string.

---

For example I want to update the memory attribute in a `task_definition.json`. The attribute must be an integer otherwise the API throws an error.

#### original file

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "cpu": 128,
      "image": "...",
      "memory": 512
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

#### jq command

```sh
export TASK_DEFINITION_MEMORY=256
jq '.containerDefinitions[0].memory = env.TASK_DEFINITION_MEMORY' task_definition.json > tmp.$$.json && mv tmp.$$.json task_definition.json
```

#### expected output

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "cpu": 128,
      "image": "...",
      "memory": 256
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

#### actual output

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "cpu": 128,
      "image": "...",
      "memory": "256"
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a pre-existing environment variable, or are you creating the environment variable because you think that is a requirement for passing information into a `jq` filter? `jq --argjson x 256 '.containerDefinitions[0].memory=$x' task_definition.json` would be sufficient.

Comment: (Even if it is pre-existing, `jq --argjson x "$TASK_DEFINITION_MEMORY" ...` would also work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What’s needed here is a call to `tonumber` to convert the string to a number. `//=` is a bit of a red herring here.

An alternative would be to pass the number into jq using `—-argjson`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the arithmetic update-assignment operator `//=` https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment

> Arithmetic update-assignment: +=, -=, *=, /=, %=, //=
>   jq has a few operators of the form a op= b, which are all equivalent to a |= . op b.
>   So, += 1 can be used to increment values, being the same as |= . + 1.

```
export TASK_DEFINITION_MEMORY=256
jq '.containerDefinitions[0].memory //= env.TASK_DEFINITION_MEMORY' task_definition.json > tmp.$$.json && mv tmp.$$.json task_definition.json
```